# Error en select MYSQ: SQL Error [1248] [42000]: Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una consulta con UNION, con el select que contine a las dos principales me sale erro, pero si ejecuto unicamente los dos sin el select q contiene a los dos, no hay error.

***Consulta:***

```
select
    nom nombre_ven,
    sum(ven) ventas,
    sum(cre) credito,
    sum(meta) metas
from
    (
    select
        c.nombre nom,
        sum(c.venta) ven,
        0 cre,
        c.meta met
    from
        ventas_por_hora_vendedor_pvp c
    where
        c.FormaPago = 'CRÉDITO ICESA'
        and c.codigoBodega = 'OQUACO'
    group by
        c.nombre
union all
    select
        c.nombre nom,
        0 ven,
        sum(c.venta) cre,
        c.meta met
    from
        ventas_por_hora_vendedor_pvp c
    where
        c.FormaPago <> 'CRÉDITO ICESA'
        and c.codigoBodega = 'OQUACO'
    group by
        c.nombre)
group by
    nombre_ven
```

me muestra el sigueonte erro: SQL Error [1248] [42000]: Every derived table must have its own alias

Answer (score 2):

Una subquery es una `derived table` si está en el `scope` de una clausula `FROM`, lo puedes ver en la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html). Básicamente, si tienes esto:

```
SELECT ... FROM (subquery)
```

Es necesario ponerle un alias, para quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT ... FROM (subquery) [AS] tbl_name ...
```

Así que en tu consulta, sólo debes ponerle un alias al final.

```
select
    nom nombre_ven,
    sum(ven) ventas,
    sum(cre) credito,
    sum(meta) metas
from
    (...subquery...) AS alias
group by
    nombre_ven
```

Answer (score 1):

Como puedes leer en la [doc. de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) las tablas derivadas poseen las siguientes características:

- Es una expresión que genera una tabla
- Esta dentro del alcance de la claúsula `FROM`
- Un alias a cada tabla derivada es obligatorio por que cada tabla debe poseer un nombre
- Así como las columnas de las tablas derivadas deben tener nombres únicos

Entonces bajo ese orden de ideas nombra a tu `UNION ALL` fuera de los parentesis de esta forma:

```
select
    nom nombre_ven,
    sum(ven) ventas,
    sum(cre) credito,
    sum(meta) metas
from
    (
    select
        c.nombre nom,
        sum(c.venta) ven,
        0 cre,
        c.meta met
    from
        ventas_por_hora_vendedor_pvp c
    where
        c.FormaPago = 'CRÉDITO ICESA'
        and c.codigoBodega = 'OQUACO'
    group by
        c.nombre
union all
    select
        c.nombre nom,
        0 ven,
        sum(c.venta) cre,
        c.meta met
    from
        ventas_por_hora_vendedor_pvp c
    where
        c.FormaPago <> 'CRÉDITO ICESA'
        and c.codigoBodega = 'OQUACO'
    group by
        c.nombre) AS derivada
group by
    nombre_ven
```