# tengo que mostrar el total de cada id_commande me sale el error 1248

Tags: mysql

La consulta que pruebo es

```
select c.id_commande, c.date_commande, c.etat_commande,(l.quantite* o.prix) 
from commande c,
(SELECT c.id_commande, count(*) FROM commande GROUP BY c.id_commande HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
inner join ligne_commande l
on   l.id_commande = c.id_commande
inner join oeuvre o
on o.id_oeuvre=l.id_oeuvre;
```

SObre estos datos:

[image: tabla]

Comment: Léete [ask] y haz el [tour] y despues puedes [edit] la pregunta para mejorarla si quieres que alguien te la tome en serio y te quiera ayudar.

Comment: La tomamos en serio pero no tenemos el poder de adivinar. Por favor, revisa los enlaces que te sugieren y luego edita la pregunta incluyendo la información faltante. Log completo de error, algún dato de prueba y salida esperada para poder probar la consulta y dar una respuesta que sí cumpla con lo que necesitas.

Answer (score 2):

EL problema es sencillo (y si incluyeras el mensaje de error completo, sería aún más evidente).

El error 1248 suele decir "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Y eso pasa porque tienes una subconsulta en el FROM ahí sin decir nada

```
(SELECT c.id_commande, count(*) 
FROM commande 
GROUP BY c.id_commande 
HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
```

pero no es claro cómo se supone que el motor debe usar esta subconsulta. Comenzando por **el nombre**. Si quieres operar sobre una subconsulta y relacionarla con otras tablas, etc., debes darle un nombre. Un alias.

```
select c.id_commande, c.date_commande, c.etat_commande,(l.quantite* o.prix) 
from commande c,
(SELECT 
    c.id_commande, 
    count(*) 
    FROM commande 
    GROUP BY c.id_commande 
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1
) omelette
inner join ligne_commande l on l.id_commande = c.id_commande
inner join oeuvre o on o.id_oeuvre=l.id_oeuvre
[LEFT|INNER|OUTER] JOIN omelette on c.xxx = omelette.yyy;
```

Ahí ya podrás decirle cómo relacionar esa subconsulta con el resto de datos (porque sin meter la subconsulta en ninguna parte, lo pones a traerte esos datos y no lo usas para nada, como están ahora mismo).

Comment: muchas gracias Alfabravo, no estoy segura de entender esta parte, podrias explicarmela [LEFT|INNER|OUTER] JOIN omelette on c.xxx = omelette.yyy; es que omellete es un alias?

Comment: omelete es un alias, si, en esta [otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/401603/error-en-select-mysq-sql-error-1248-42000-every-derived-table-must-have-it) encontrarás más información sobre los alias. Si esta respuesta ha solucionado tu pregunta inicial deberias marcarla como aceptada para que no quede pendiente para siempre. Puedes aprender que hacer con las respuestas que te dan visitando este [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), gracias.